# Models of an Elliptic Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then it has a model $W$ satisfying $W(\mathbb{Z})=E(\mathbb{Q})$. This means $E$ only has integer points. But this is not true. What went wrong?

Comment: What do you call integer points for $E$? Solutions $(x,y)$ where $x,y$ are integers? But that’s not what the existence of $W$ says… Note that, by the valuative criterion, any proper integral $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme $S$ should verify $S(\mathbb{Z})=S(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Great. I see it now.